# C# value type and String

Tags: c#, tostring, value-type

This is a homework question, which is why it might be somewhat odd(also apologize if the title isn't very good)

Assuming that *v1* is a value type of type *X* that redefines *ToString*, is there any difference between using *Console.WriteLine(v1)* and *Console.WriteLine(v1.toString())*?

Comment: Did you try it and looked what it gave you?

Comment: Is this a trick question? toString isn't a valid C# method. In C#, it's ToString, so the answer will be YES, there's a difference.

Comment: Wouldn't have expected a course to cover such subtle points of C#.

Comment: @CodeInChaos neither the professor would expected it.

Comment: my bad, I copied it wrong(my usual programming language is Java), in the question its actually ToString

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest answer is that "yes, there's a difference". Obviously the important thing is that you know what that difference *is* though. I won't tell you that, but I'll tell you how to investigate it...

- Write a short program which contains a custom value type as described, and *both* `Console.WriteLine(v1)` and `Console.WriteLine(v1.ToString())` in a `Main` method
- Compile the program
- Run `ildasm` (or Reflector in IL mode) and look at the difference between the method invocations

  - Which method overload is invoked in each case?
  - What happens to the value in each case?

Questions which you might want to think about and which might get you extra credit:

- Is there any difference if you use a custom class instead of a struct?
- Can you think of any way that `Console.WriteLine` could have been designed which would have removed any inefficiency you've noticed?

Comment: If he'll tell that to professor. i am sure he is gonna look at his face for a moment.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a small difference regarding boxing, but for normal implementations of `ToString` it doesn't change the observable behavior of the program(beyond a minimal performance hit). You should figure out when boxing occurs.

Does passing `v1` to `Console.WriteLine` box it?

Does calling `v1.ToString()` box `v1`? Why/Why not? Does it matter that the type overrides `ToString`? i.e. is there a difference between calling methods inherited from `Object`, and overridden methods?

Comment: Example program that exhibits an observable difference: http://ideone.com/p1omq (Note that its `ToString` implementation is evil, don't do that in real code)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's OK to answer homework questions, as it feels like I'm doing you a dis-service :)

When calling Console.Writeline(v1) without a ToString() method will cause the console to also call `ToString()` to get the actual value.

Also, I'm not sure if your professor is a "trick question" kind of guy, but in C#, there is no "toString()" method - it's actually "ToString()" (note the user of capital "To")